# InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Enrollments' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I am new to Asp.Net Core (Even to Asp.Net and web). I am using Asp.Net Core 2 with MySQL, using Pomelo.EntityFrameWorkCore.MySql (2.0.1) driver. I just created a custom dbcontext with Courses and Enrollments table, along with the default created ApplicationDbContext. The Primary Key for Enrollments is a composite key, comprising of UserId and CourseId. Below is the code :

```
public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Enrollments> Enrollments { get; set; }

    public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Courses>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("courses");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
                .HasName("Coursescol_UNIQUE")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Duration).HasColumnType("time");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(45);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollments>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.CourseId });

            entity.ToTable("enrollments");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CourseId)
                .HasName("fk_Courses_Enrollments_CourseId_idx");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId)
                .HasName("fk_Users_Enrollments_CourseId_idx");

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.UserId, e.CourseId })
                .HasName("UniqueEnrollment")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.CourseId).HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Course)
                .WithMany(p => p.Enrollments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CourseId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("fk_Courses_Enrollments_CourseId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.Enrollments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("fk_Users_Enrollments_UserId");
        });
    }

}
```

The Program.cs goes like :

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<CustomDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

The configure services method in Startup.cs goes like :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDbContext<CustomDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

The Courses Model goes like :

```
public partial class Courses
{
    public Courses()
    {
        Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollments>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollments> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

The Enrollments Model goes like :

```
public partial class Enrollments
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public Courses Course { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

The applicationUser model goes like :

```
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollments>();
    }

    public ICollection<Enrollments> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

**Now, here's what I've tried so far :**

1. If i add Course and Enrollment model to the ApplicationDBContext, then everything goes fine.
2. If in CustomDBContext i have a non-composite primary Key, even then it works fine. (I just tried another example)

Can somebody please throw some light on why is this error ? Is this the intended way to handle such a case ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `Enrollments` entity has been discovered by `ApplicationDbContext` through `ApplicationUser.Enrollments` navigation property. This is explained in the [Including & Excluding Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types) - **Conventions** section of the EF Core documentation:

> By convention, types that are exposed in `DbSet` properties on your context are included in your model. In addition, types that are mentioned in the `OnModelCreating` method are also included. **Finally, any types that are found by recursively exploring the navigation properties of discovered types are also included in the model.**

I guess now you see the problem. The `Enrollments` is discovered and included in the `ApplicationDbContext`, but there is no fluent configuration for that entity there, so EF uses only the default conventions and data annotations. And of course composite PK requires fluent configuration. And even there wasn't a composite PK, it's still incorrect to ignore the existing fluent configuration. Note that `Courses` is also included in the `ApplicationDbContext` by the aforementioned recursive process (through `Enrollments.Courses` navigation property). Etc. for other referenced classes.

Note that the same applies in the other direction. `ApplicationUser` and all referenced from it are discovered and included in the `CustomDbContext` w/o their fluent configuration.

The conclusion - don't use separate contexts containing interrelated entities. In your case, put all the entities in the `ApplicationDBContext`.